# CV2 create blurry videos

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
size = 80,80
duration = 2
fps = 25
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264'), fps, size)
for l in range(fps * duration):
    data = np.zeros( (80,80,3), dtype=np.uint8 )
    for k in range(80):
        data[40][k]=[255,0,0]
    out.write(data)
out.release()
```

When I want to create an video from an array of pixels (in the example a line, but I need to create more complex images) the result is very blurry and difficult to read.

Is there a specific format to create smooth pixels with cv2 or I need another video library?

For the input, it's an array 80*80 like in this code but with my data
And I get the second image when converting to video

[Imput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGUoi.png)

[Output (same with .avi or .mp4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILlwM.png)

Comment: Please post the input, and output that you are getting.

Comment: maybe you need different coded - or animated GIF - which use less loosless compresion.

Comment: it is very small image - 80x80 - and it is almost black. How do you know it is burry? Do you watch it in original size? If you watch resized then it may be blurry but it not problem with video but because video player had to resize it.

Comment: [OpenCV blurring](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html)